# Adding new table from admin view

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am looking for a way to add a new table in one of two ways:

- Add a new model to app from admin view.

, or:

- Two apps A and B. If a new entry to the first model in model A is created then it will create a new model in app B.

Are either of these possible in `Django`?

Comment: There's a whole lot of complications that can arise from this, but [django-mutant](https://github.com/charettes/django-mutant) is one of the best libraries to assist

Comment: I think my question may be confusing, I am having trouble with it. I don't want to change any schema. In short, I want to create a new "table" if an entry is added to another table. Almost a table in table (model in model) type situation.